# Passing object as a prop of component in react

Tags: reactjs

I have an object which is in state, I would want to send this object to a child component and again get it back after updating the object.How do I do it ?

This is the parent component.

```
class TextN extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    console.log('Text constructor called');
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    w:'auto',
    h:'auto',
    widthF:32,
    heightF:23,
    rightClick:false,
    textObj:{
        modalShow: false,
        message: 'Text',
        textPosY:5,
        textPosX:5,
        degreeOfRot:0,
        maxNumberOfChar:0,
        fontSize: 15,
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontfamily:'arial',
    },
  }
}

onDrag(e,ui){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(ui);
}

onDragStop(e,ui){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(ui);
}

editText(){
    var tObj = this.state.textObj;
    tObj.modalShow = true;
    this.setState({ textObj: tObj }); 
}

getData(dataText){
    var tObj = this.state.textObj;
    tObj.modalShow =false;
    tObj.message = dataText;
    this.setState({ textObj: tObj }); 
}


render() {
    var style = {

        titleText:{
            fontFamily:this.state.textObj.fontfamily,
            fontSize:this.state.textObj.fontSize,
            fontWeight:this.state.textObj.fontWeight,
        },
    }
    return (
        <Rnd ref={c => { this.rnd = c; }}
        initial={{
            x: this.state.textObj.textPosX,
            y: this.state.textObj.textPosY,
            width: this.state.w,
            height: this.state.h,
        }}
        style={style1}
        minWidth={this.state.widthF}
        minHeight={this.state.heightF}
        maxWidth={500}
        maxHeight={500}
        bounds={'parent'}
        //onDrag={this.onDrag.bind(this)}
        onDragStop={this.onDragStop.bind(this)}
        isResizable={{top:false, right:true, bottom:false, left:false, topRight:false, bottomRight:false, bottomLeft:false, topLeft:false}}
        >
        <label style={style.titleText} onClick={this.editText.bind(this)}>{this.state.textObj.message}</label>
        **<TModal show={this.state.textObj} callBack={this.getData.bind(this)}/>**
        </Rnd>
    )
}
```

}

And in the child component I receive the props as an object I update the object with new values and I return the object to the callback function.

```
    class TextModal extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    console.log('Modal constructor called');
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMod: this.props.show.modalShow,
      text:'Text',
      fontModal:false,
      fontObject:{},
      textObj:{},
      displayColorPicker:false,
      color: {
      r: '241',
      g: '112',
      b: '19',
      a: '1',
    },
    };
    }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('inside components will recieve');
    this.setState({showMod : this.props.show.modalShow});
    this.setState({text:this.props.show.message});
    this.setState({textObj:this.props.show});
    console.log(this.props.show);
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    if(this.state.showMod !== nextState.showMod){

        return true;

    }else if(this.state.fontModal !== nextState.fontModal){

        return true;

    }else if(this.state.displayColorPicker !== nextState.displayColorPicker){

        return true;

    }else if(this.state.color !== nextState.color){

        return true;

    }else if(this.state.text !== nextState.text){

        return true;
    }

    return false;

}



onSubmit(e){
    this.props.callBack(this.state.textObj);
}

close() {
    console.log('close is called');
    this.setState({ showMod: false });
    this.setState({fontModal:false});
}



handleChange(e){
    this.setState({text:e.target.value});
}





render(){

    return(
        <div>
        <Modal show={this.state.showMod} onHide={this.close.bind(this)}>
            <Modal.Header style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                <Modal.Title>Text</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
            <form>
            <label>Text:</label><input type="text" ref={(c) => this.title = c} name="title" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.text}/><br />
            <label>Current Left Position:</label><input type="number" value={this.state.textObj.textPosX}/><br />
            <label>Current Top Position:</label><input type="number" value={this.state.textObj.textPosY}/><br />
            <label>Degree of Rotation:</label><input type="number" value={this.state.textObj.degreeOfRot}/><br />
            <label>Max # of Characters:</label><input type="number" value={this.state.textObj.maxNumberOfChar}/><br />
            <label>Click to select Font:</label><input style={{fontFamily:this.state.fontObject.fontFamily,fontWeight:this.state.fontObject.fontStyle}} value={this.state.fontObject.fontFamily} onClick={this.showFontModal.bind(this)}/><br />
            <label>Click to select Color:</label><input style={{backgroundColor:styles.color.background}} onClick={this.handleColorPicker.bind(this)}/><br />
            </form>
            { this.state.displayColorPicker ? <div style={ styles.popover }>
            <div style={ styles.cover } onClick={ this.handleColorClose.bind(this) }/>
                <SketchPicker color={ this.state.color } onChange={ this.handleChangeColor.bind(this) } />
            </div> : null }
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small" onClick={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>Ok</Button>
                <Button bsStyle="warning" bsSize="small" onClick={this.close.bind(this)}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using anything like redux to manage your state, or do you just manage some state object yourself at an application level?

Comment: I am not using redux I am managing the states on my own.

Comment: I would probably define methods on the parent component and pass those down to the child component. One method would return the value from state you want the child component to have, the other would take a value and update state as appropriate. Encapsulate the logic of these in methods on the parent component instance and pass them as props to the child.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A child should never mutate its props, and the dataflow in React is one way down.

If your child component want to send data to its parent, you can pass a callback function to the child, so the child component can send the data back via the function.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  cb (dataFromChild) {
    console.log(dataFromChild) // 100
  }

  render () {
    return <Child cb={this.cb} someData={99} />
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    this.props.cb(this.props.someData + 1)
  }

  render () {
    return <h1>Child</h1>
  }
}
```

When your application becomes more complex, it's the time to use a state management solution, like Redux and MobX.

Comment: I have edited my question with the program. I have considered using redux in future but this is a POC that I am trying to accomplish and I need only this much as of now. @CodinCat

Comment: Your code looks fine, what's the problem for now? If it doesn't work then I will need to see the full code

Comment: It give me this error. "invariant.js:44 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child". I have added the complete code now.

Comment: The message says you are rendering an object directly, which is not allowed in React. Check the line number of this error and fix it.

Comment: I figured it out, as I was passing an object before and trying to render it. It worked when I used an array to do the same.